# $n! =$ the product of consecutive integers.

Tags: number-theory

Can $n!$ be the product of $k$ consecutive integers for $k > 1$? (Not including the degenerate cases such as when $k = 2$, then $1\cdot2 = 2!$ and $2\cdot 3 = 3!$, and so on.)

I am asking not for $n!$ to be divisible by $n$ consecutive integers, I am asking for $n!$ to *equal* the product of $k$ consecutive integers, implying that $n$ is not necessarily equal to $k$ (And when $n = k$, then clearly there exists an answer, namely $n! = (1)(2)(3)...(k)$)

Comment: $5! = 4\cdot 5\cdot 6$? $6! = 8\cdot 9\cdot 10$.

Comment: $n!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot ...\cdot n$ is defined so as to be the product of $n$ consecutive integers.

Comment: $n!$ can be the product of $n$ consecutive integers as well as $n-1$ consecutive integers.

Comment: Also $(k-1)!$ can be written as product of $k!-k$ integers in the following way: $(k+1)\cdot\dots\cdot k!$.

Comment: 6! = 720 can be written as the product of three other consecutive integers: 8*9*10
Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 7):

The formula $$(n!-1)!=\frac{(n!)!}{n!}=\prod_{k=n+1}^{n!} k$$ gives an infinite family of examples.