# Question about the product of some consecutive integers being factorials.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, factorial, natural-numbers

A nice little curio.

**1** = 1!

2(**3**) = 6 = 3!

4(5)(**6**) = 120 = 5!

7(8)(9)(**10**) = 5040 = 7!

Are there any other examples of products of 'some' consecutive integers equalling factorials?  Is there a proof that there is not?  To be clear I am asking if the pattern above continues for *all* the triangular numbers (in bold)?  It does not appear to hold for the next few examples so I conjecture that the pattern only holds for the triangular numbers above.  Is this conjecture known or proven/disproven?

Comment: Could you please include in your post the motivation for this question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$n! =$ the product of consecutive integers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482294/n-the-product-of-consecutive-integers)? More specifically, there's also [n! as a product of $3$ consecutive integers](/q/1962195). There are more related posts in this [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=product+consecutive+integers+%22n%21%22) results list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer John and I apologise for not being clear in my question, this has been amended and you may have an answer.  Is so please comment.

Comment: This was asked but not answered in 'Four fractions of certain factorials give another factorial'.  Therefore, I am happy to delete this question as a duplicate.